# Firebird: show tables command shows no result in different environment

Tags: firebird, docker

I'm using firebird with docker with the image `jacobalberty/firebird:2.5.8-sc`

I use it in local and in the remote server. The problem is the database seems unreadable in the remote server, it says `no table in this database` even though in the local environment it works fine.

I use isql command inside the container to run the query

```
root@8978428b8a97:/usr/local/firebird/bin# ./isql
Use CONNECT or CREATE DATABASE to specify a database
SQL> CONNECT "/firebird/data/data.GDB"
CON> user 'guest' password 'guest';
Database:  "/firebird/data/data.GDB", User: guest
SQL>show tables;
There are no tables in this database
```

I thought maybe the database file is corrupted, but I already uploaded the database file several times using filezilla, and checking the md5sum then compare the hash, it's already the same.

## Update

The database is originally from Windows 10 64 bit, it's from another application (probably 32bit application) my employer used. this is the result running `gstat /firebird/data/data.GDB -h`

```
Database "/firebird/data/data.GDB"
Gstat execution time Fri Jan  4 08:02:15 2019

Database header page information:
        Flags                   0
        Checksum                12345
        Generation              211656
        Page size               4096
        ODS version             11.1
        Oldest transaction      211394
        Oldest active           211546
        Oldest snapshot         211546
        Next transaction        211549
        Bumped transaction      1
        Sequence number         0
        Next attachment ID      736
        Implementation ID       16
        Shadow count            0
        Page buffers            0
        Next header page        0
        Database dialect        3
        Creation date           May 26, 2010 16:09:32
        Attributes              force write, no reserve

    Variable header data:
        Sweep interval:         20000
        *END*
```

In Windows I use `flamerobin` to read the database directly and used it in `node.js` application using the same user and password, and it works.

Comment: What is the exact platform where the database was originally created (version, OS, bitness, etc)? Also include the header page information from `gstat -h`. Databases can't always be copied between platforms, and sometimes backup and restore is the only way.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it's originally created on Windows 10 64bit the database is from another application. I already updated my question with the result of `gstat -h`

Comment: I keep forgetting the exact rules, but IIRC, moving between Windows and Linux (the docker image) will require a backup and restore, especially if they have differing bitness. I'll try and test it to make sure.

Comment: I tried using the backup file (.fbk) I successfully created the backup file using `flamerobin` but when I tried to restore the database it says ` ERROR: Your login SYSDBA is same as one of the SQL role name.` probably the previous application is blocking the use of `SYSDBA` user

Comment: Then restore with a different user than sysdba